# Vercel build complaining about .env.local?

Tags: deployment, build, vercel

My NextJS app build is compiling successfully but then suddenly errors because of something in `.env.local` — I was under the impression that this file was ignored, and besides, nothing has changed in this file. Any idea why this happens?

The last few lines in the log before the error:

```
16:55:48.579    info  - Compiled successfully
16:55:48.579    info  - Collecting page data...
16:55:49.442    Error: Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is searching for the MONGODB_URI environment variable, please find where you use that variable. If you need that then create an env file as .env.local and put your MONGODB_URI code into it.

```
MONGODB_URI=YOUR_VALUE
```